# В чем причина ошибки Termux : Error adding monitor mode interface?

Tags: python, termux

В интернете пишут, что нужен беспроводной драйвер для AAarch64 MediaTek. Как его установить на MIUI?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуй начать использовать знаки препинания.

Comment: Я что-то очень сильно сомневаюсь, что андроид предоставит термуксу прямой доступ к оборудованию, особенно без root

Comment: У меня есть рут

Answer (score -1):

Android не имеет доступа к режиму монитора. Даже если будет подходящий адаптер, то вряд ли что-то получится!

Comment: Постарайтесь добавлять более развёрнутые ответы, дополнить ответ можно нажав кнопку [edit].